# Не пускает в phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, debian, phpmyadmin

В Debian 9 при установке MySQL не спросило пароль, видимо, подставился рутовый.
Потом установил phpMyAdmin, при вопросе о пароле просто нажал <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Теперь при попытке войти в phpMyAdmin с логином root и без пароля не пускает:

> Login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see AllowNoPassword)

Уже какие пароли и логины не пробовал - без результата.
Потом и переустанавливал и то, и другое - не помогает.

Comment: `sudo mysql_secure_installation` попробуйте.

Comment: Выполнил все, но все-равно ошибка входа: "mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1698): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'". Не влияет, что я вхожу удаленно? Сервер ребутил.

Comment: Пару лет назад с лишним была подобная проблема с паролем к PHPMyAdmin, но на Ubuntu. Пришлось сбрасывать пароль root'a и устанавливать новый. Делал, как описано здесь - https://vps.ua/wiki/install-linux-vps/databases/mysql/how-reset-root-password-mysql/

Comment: https://sysadmin.ru/articles/vxod-v-phpmyadmin-bez-parolya-allownopassword - попробуйте это, чтобы войти без пароля.

Answer (score 0):

После установки можно поискать в логах `/var/log/mysqld.log` значение `temporary password`, либо как в комментарии написали, запустить смену пароля командой `mysql_secure_installation`

Comment: Такого файла нет. Стоит mariaDB.

Comment: MariaDB или MySQL таки?